# MongoDB and Spring JPA integration is throwing error

Tags: spring, mongodb, jpa

I am trying to integrate Spring JPA with MongoDB. My intention is to just retrieve data from mongo DB. I am getting the below error while injecting my repository.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.org.coop.society.data.mongo.repositories.MaterialMasterRepository com.org.coop.security.service.MongoService.materialMasterRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'materialMasterRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
```

My configuration snippet is given below.

**TestMongoDBConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.abc.data.mongo.repositories"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abc")
@PropertySource("classpath:applicationTest.properties")
public class TestMongoDBConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
@Autowired
private Environment env;

 @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "retail";
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongo() throws Exception {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        return client;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.abc.data.mongo.entities";
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), getDatabaseName());
    }
}
```

**MaterialMaster.java** in com.abc.data.mongo.entities package

```
@Document(collection = "materialMaster")
public class MaterialMaster {

@Id
private Long materialId;

@Field
private String name;
```

**MaterialMasterRepository.java** in com.abc.data.mongo.repositories package

```
public interface MaterialMasterRepository extends MongoRepository<MaterialMaster, Long> {
}
```

**MongoService.java** in com.abc.service package

```
@Service
public class MongoService {

    @Autowired
    private MaterialMasterRepository materialMasterRepository;

    public void getMaterials() {
        List<MaterialMaster> materials = materialMasterRepository.findAll();

        System.out.println(materials);
    }
}
```

**Junit** class looks like below

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abc")
@ContextHierarchy({
     @ContextConfiguration(classes={TestMongoDBConfig.class})
})
public class ModuleWSTest {
    @Autowired
    private MongoService mongoService;
    @Test
    public void testModule() {

        mongoService.getMaterials();
    }
}
```

I have tried all possible changes (as per my knowledge) but no luck. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is little confusing. I was using latest spring-data-mongodb (1.8.4.RELEASE). Once I downgraded the dependency to 1.6.0.RELEASE then the above configuration started working.